On ${\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left[ 12+x^2+3x^2 \left(1-x\coth(x/2)\right) {\text{csch}}^2(x/2) \right]\frac{dx}{x^4} =\zeta(3)/\zeta(2)}$

How to show that:
$$ \color{red}{I_{_1}} =\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left[ 12 + x^{2} + 3x^{2}\left(1\color{red}{-}x\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right] \frac{dx}{x^{4}} =\color{red}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)}} $$
$\zeta(s)$ Riemann Zeta.

In a similar integral:
$$ \color{green}{I_{_2}} =\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left[ 36 - x^{2} - 3x^{2}\left(1\color{green}{+}x\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right] \frac{dx}{x^{4}} =\color{green}{0} $$
Where the derivative: 
$$ \left[\text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^{\prime} =-\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) $$
Allow the calculation of:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\,&\, \int\left(1\color{green}{+}x\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{x}\,\text{csch}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \\[4mm] 
\,&\implies \color{green}{I_{_2}} = \left[-\frac{12}{x^{3}}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{3}{x}\,\text{csch}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} =\color{green}{0} 
\end{align} 
$$
Nevertheless, this will not help much in:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\,&\, \int\left(1\color{red}{-}x\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2} \\[4mm] 
\,&\, \int\left(2-1-x\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2} \\[4mm] 
\,&\, = \frac{1}{x}\,\text{csch}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) +2\int\text{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2} 
\end{align} 
$$
Thanks. 


Maybe it would help that substituting $x\to 2x$ gives the integrand as:$\frac3{2x^4}+\frac1{2x^2}+\frac{3\operatorname{csch}^2(x)}{2x^2}-\frac{\coth(x)\operatorname{csch}^2(x)}x=\frac1{2x^2}-\sum\limits_{n\ne 0,n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{3(x-\pi i n)}{2x^2(x+\pi i n)^3}$

Also, combining the integrals is not helping much: $$ \begin{align} \color{red}{I_{1}}+\color{green}{I{2}} &= 6\int\limits_0^\infty\left[+\frac{8}{x^4} -\frac{\coth(x/2),\text{csch}^{2}(x/2)}{x} \right]dx \ \color{red}{I{1}}-\color{green}{I{_2}} &= 2\int\limits_0^\infty\left[-\frac{12}{x^4} +\frac{1+3,\text{csch}^{2}(x/2)}{x^2} \right]dx \end{align} $$

$\DeclareMathOperator{csch}{csch} \DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}$From a comment, where the asker added $I_1+I_2$, substitute $x\to2x$:
$$\int_0^\infty\left[12+x^2+3x^2\left(1-x\coth\left(\frac x2\right)\right) \csch^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right] \frac{dx}{x^4}=6\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4}-\frac{\coth(x)\csch^2(x)}xdx= \int_0^\infty\frac6{x^4}-\frac3x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\coth(x)dx$$
Next, use $\coth(x)$’s series expansion to have the $n=0$ term cancel out $\frac6{x^4}$:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac6{x^4}-\frac3x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\coth(x)dx=-6\int_0^\infty\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\frac{x^2-3\pi^2n^2}{(x^2+\pi^2n^2)^3}dx$$
It can be shown that the indefinite integral is:
$$-6\int_0^\infty\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\frac{x^2-3\pi^2n^2}{(x^2+\pi^2n^2)^3}dx=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\frac6{\pi^3n^3}\left.\left(\frac{\pi n x(x^2+2\pi^2n^2)}{(x^2+\pi^2n^2)^2}+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{\pi n}\right)\right)\right|_0^\infty$$
Then, since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi n x(x^2+2\pi^2n^2)}{(x^2+\pi^2n^2)^2}+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{\pi n}\right)=\sgn(n)\frac\pi 2$, we get:
$$6\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4}-\frac{\coth(x)\csch^2(x)}xdx=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z/0}\frac{3\sgn(n)}{\pi^2n^3}=-\frac3{\pi^2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac1{n^3}+\frac3{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\\\implies \boxed{\int_0^\infty\left[12+x^2+3x^2\left(1-x\coth\left(\frac x2\right)\right) \csch^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right] \frac{dx}{x^4}=\frac{6\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}=\frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)}}$$
